# Unable To Connect To MAMP Server From Other Devices

Tags: apache, mamp, remote-access, mamp-pro

I have MAMP PRO running locally on my machine (Mavericks).  I can connect find to localhost and apache is running on port 80.
The test website I have set up is served.  I can browse to it via http:// my-local-host (have to put a dash in because stack exchange doesn't like URLs) or http://mymachinename.local or http://XXX.XXX.X.XX (my ipaddress).

It's not working remotely though from either iPhone or iPad.  I have tried turning off the firewall.  I have tried adding a rule to the firewall to allow incoming connections to httpd.  Neither work.

I also have Little Snitch installed.  I tried turning off Little snitch and also creating a rule to allow traffic through to port 80 via httpd.  Neither work.

Anyone else had similar issues and found a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is DNS.
MAMP writes your Hosts to /etc/hosts.

Example:

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

Your Iphone's host file has no such entry. This is why it does not work.
You need e.g. a "DNS-server", which you can enter in
`Settings - Wlan - static` as Router on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem would be addressed if you use the Dynamic DNS option in MAMP PRO.  Then, using a third party company like noIP.com, you could setup myTestBox.ddns.net and pull up your website on your iPad.